# Backgrounds not rendering correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

Or not rendering at all, I should say...

http://samnorris.co.nz

testing in Version 34.0.1847.131, two of my fixed background sections are not displaying, for example:

[image: Look ma, no background]

No idea what I've done that Chrome doesn't like - not a big user of Chrome actually (I'm a Firefox man), although I realize that's no excuse for a web designer! Works fine in Firefox.

Is it that the multiple backgrounds technique is not compatible with Chrome or something? (as I just realized only these two sections use it)

I checked to see it wasn't something stupid like an AdBlock plugin blocking something from loading, but that doesn't appear to be the case..

.spacesuit-bg and .interact-bg are the two culprits, both with somewhat similar CSS...

```
.spacesuit-bg {
    background: url("../img/spacesuit-bg.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;   
    color: #fff;
    height: 680px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    display: block;
}

.multiplebgs .spacesuit-bg {
    background-image: url("../img/tech-seperator.png"), url("../img/tech-seperator-bottom.png"), url("../img/spacesuit-bg.jpg");
    background-position: 0 0, 0 bottom, center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:auto auto, auto auto, !important;
    -moz-background-size:auto auto, auto auto, cover!important;
    -o-background-size:auto auto, auto auto, !important;
    background-size:auto auto, auto auto, cover !important;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .spacesuit-bg {
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1240px) {
    .spacesuit-bg {
        background-attachment: scroll, scroll, fixed;
    /*    min-height: 800px; */
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:2503px) {
    .spacesuit-bg {
        -webkit-background-size:auto auto, auto auto,;
        -moz-background-size:auto auto, auto auto, cover;
        -o-background-size:auto auto, auto auto,;
        background-size:auto auto, auto auto, cover;
        max-height: 0;
        padding: 400px 0;
    }
}
```

Second background-less section:

```
.interact-bg {
    background: transparent url("../img/interact-bg.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;    
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    max-height: 980px;
    padding: 20% 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);  
}
.multiplebgs .interact-bg {
    background-image: url("../img/interact-seperator.png"), url("../img/interact-seperator-bottom.png"), url("../img/interact-bg.jpg");
    background-position: 0 0, 0 bottom, center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto, auto auto, cover!important;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .interact-bg {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1240px) {
    .interact-bg {
        background-attachment: scroll, scroll, fixed;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:2503px) {
    .interact-bg {
        background-size: auto auto, auto auto, cover;
        max-height: 0;
        padding: 400px 0;
    }
}

.interact-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.interact-wrapper:before { 
    /* this is the important part */ 
    content: ''; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    /* this just takes care of whitespace added by having display:inline-block (there are other methods) */ 
    margin-left: -0.25em; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes from the background image URLs?

Comment: I have not - I would not have thought it should make any difference whether image URLs have surrounding quotes or not? at least that's what I've been led to believe all these years..

Comment: I agree which is why I didn't put it as an answer. The problem sounds like a quirk and I seem to recall something where the quotes made a difference so I think it's worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `background-attachement` property (for my browser width that would be:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1240px) {
.interact-bg {
    background-attachment: scroll, scroll, fixed;
}
```

or more in detail the `fixed` value, as it fixes the background to the top left of the viewport (not element). Change fixed to scroll and you'll see the background (just to test it)

Comment: That works, many thanks - although the spheres are not animated, strange... Does Chrome not support rotate transforms ect.?

Comment: Yes, Chrome supports that (you're using it because of hardware acceleration I assume). I think the initial problem is coming from a Javascript issue (there are quite some errors on your site). You could just remove `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` and everything would work fine. Otherwise, check your JS :)

Comment: Removing the webkit-transform: translate3d property didn't seem to help unfortunately. Guess I've got some Javascript debugging to do! I attempted to "re-organize" all of the JS the other night for optimization reasons, hopefully that isn't what has screwed things up... could I ask what tool you used to verify the errors, btw?

Comment: Well, I'm no expert at JS debugging or anything, and I haven't used Firebug a whole lot - but after checking the Firebug console I'm only getting one error: TypeError: jQuery.event.handle is undefined on line 214. Although it is continuously recurring, which isn't too good obviously... if you can see other errors on your end I'd be interested to know :)   edit: sorry, make that two errors (total, from what I can see)

Comment: nevermind - got it fixed! squashed those two bugs and was just missing the required vendor prefixes for Chrome so it animates fine now